# C++ how to stop service during the doing work and process

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, service

I am newer in `C++` and windows service application.
I Can't use `ATL` for windows service.
I want write the basic code for windows service that Understand them.

now, I write a sample code for windows service That into one loop exist :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 600; i++) // for this source 600 equal 1 hours
```

Now, I want if user in `i = 100` `SCM` clicked `stop the service`, this `forloop` in any `i`, `break` and service be stop.

can anybody to help me?

Comment: If you have a *long* running loop (unless you do something that takes a long time, a loop iterating just 600 times would be very short) you can poll the SCM inside the loop to check for stop requests.

Comment: 600 loop in my source is 1 hours .

Comment: That's the "unless" part. So poll the SCM multiple times inside the loop? And if the code is waiting for events, add the events from the SCM to the list of events to listen to.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: you can't actually poll the SCM, there's no interface for doing so.  Nor does the SCM provide an event object for you to check.  You have to implement some suitable cross-thread communications mechanism inside your control handler function; this can be as simple as a global variable, provided you access it in a thread-safe way.

Comment: @HarryJohnston You're right, it was to long ago I wrote a service. But practically it really doesn't matter, the only difference is *what* to poll (calling some API function versus checking e.g. an atomic boolean flag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I try and get the best solution :

1. you must use the thread
2. and you must add Event to your program
3. Eventually, you can use the follow code for check event happened or not?

   [WaitForSingleObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx)(g_ServiceStopEvent, 0) != WAIT_OBJECT_0

Note: don't forget in ServiceCtrlHandler function you must use the :

```
in case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP use : SetEvent(g_ServiceStopEvent);
```

god luck